# Как преобразовать строку с содержимым массива в массив?

Tags: php

Есть массив в виде строки:

```
'key' => [
    [
        'subkey_1' => 'value_1',
        'subkey_2' => 'value_2'
    ]
]
```

А так он выглядит в самой строке:

```
"""
\r\n
\t\t'key' => [\r\n
\t\t\t[\r\n
\t\t\t\t'subkey_1' => 'value_1',\r\n
\t\t\t\t'subkey_2' => 'value_2'\r\n
\t\t\t]\r\n
\t\t]\r\n
\t
"""
```

Можно ли как-то преобразовать эту строку в массив? Функция `json_decode()` не берет.

Comment: откуда вы его взяли?

Comment: @splash58 из разметки, там только так, в другом виде получить не удастся. Возможно, как-нибудь при помощи `eval` можно сделать?

Comment: если уверены в источнике данных, eval вполне решение

Comment: @splash58, спасибо. Да, в источнике уверен, массив на 100% всегда правильно организован.

Answer (score 1):

Это не `json`, а массив в коде `php`. Вам нужно либо писать свой десериализатор либо перед отправкой использовать `json_encode()`.